# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

Eu criei os pacotes DAO, MODEL, CONTROLLER e um teste 
Ele roda normal com o servidor, persiste no banco normal mas através da camada de visão. Eu queria testar no main rodando com java application e setar os valores do carro antes de construir o resto como páginas jsp para ver logo se tem algum erro.

Na classe teste do pacote TESTE  está assim:

```
import model.Carro;
import dao.CarroDAO;

public class Teste {

    public static void main (String[] args){

    Carro carro = new Carro();

    carro.setMarca("Chevrolet");
    carro.setModelo("Cruze");
    carro.setChassi(2.4);
    carro.setRenavam(2.5);
    carro.setMotor(1.6F);

    new CarroDAO().save(carro); 
 }  
}
```

Só que quando eu seto está dando essas exceções:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at dao.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:19)
at dao.CarroDAO.<init>(CarroDAO.java:21)
at teste.Teste.main(Teste.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at dao.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:16)
```

Eu inseri o driver do jdbc postgres.

A classe ConnectionFactory:

```
package DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/carro";
private String username = "postgres";
private String password = "";


public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Você baixou o driver do postgre  e adicionou o jar no classpath?

Comment: Seria legal você implementar um teste unitário dentro da IDE. Melhor do que criar um main.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe só um instante que estou vendo isso.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe fiz o que você mandou :). MUITO OBRIGADA! Deu certo.

Comment: Faltou acrescentar o jar no classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baixe o jar [deste site](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), e adicione no classpath do seu projeto. A causa do erro é porque a classe `org.postgresql.Driver` não foi localizada, provavelmente porque o jar do driver não foi adicionado no classpath do projeto.

Outro detalhe, se estiver usando versões mais recentes do jdk, como 1.6 ou mais nova(que possui versão 4 do jdbc), não é necessário informar o `Class.forName`, **desde que o jar do driver do banco esteja adicionado no classpath do projeto**, o próprio jdbc [já registra automaticamente](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html).

Comment: Eu já estava com o driver, só faltava mesmo incluir no classpath.

Comment: Agora cada projeto eu preciso adicionar o jar no classpath é isso?

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Sim

Comment: @AlineGonzaga sim, todos os projetos que você precisar de fazer conexão com o banco, é necessário adicionar o driver correspondente a este banco no classpath, para que io jdbc possa identifica-lo.