# Por que utilizar Class.forName ao conectar com o banco de dados?

Tags: java, jdbc

Para a conexão com banco de dados, além da inclusão do driver JDBC, a maioria dos artigos e exemplos utilizam o método estático `Class.forName(String)`.
Veja o exemplo com o MySQL:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

ou até

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Algumas citações:

- ["Criando uma conexão Java + MySQL Server" em DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-uma-conexao-java-mysql-server/16753)
- ["MySQL and Java JDBC" em Voegella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

O que faz o `Class.forName(String)` e o `newInstance()`? Não é possível importar o pacote `com.mysql.jdbc` e instanciar um objeto `Driver` para a conexão, por exemplo?

Comment: Isso não é mais necessário desde o java 1.6. Anteriormente era necessário 
 para que o java encontrasse o driver correto. Mas após a versão citada, o proprio compilador já procura o driver mais adequado e se não encontra, lança exceção.

Comment: Relacionada: [java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113508/28595)

Comment: @Articuno Quase. Não é o compilador que faz isso. É a classe `DriverManager` que faz em tempo de execução. O compilador mesmo, não quer nem saber se a classe necessária existe ou não.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## TL;DR

- Não é necssário usar-se `Class.forName(String)` a partir do Java 6, mas fazê-lo mesmo assim pode fazer o seu programa recusar-se a ser inicializado caso o driver não estiver no classpath.
- Não existe e nem nunca existiu necessidade em utilizar-se o `newInstance()` nesse caso. Isso não serve para absolutamente nada.
- Você pode importar e instanciar o driver diretamente se quiser sem problemas.

---

Seguem as explicações detalhadas:

## O `Class.forName(String)` é realmente necessário?

Vou copiar um trecho [desta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184301/132):

> O processo de inicialização do driver, usando o `Class.forName` não é mais necessário nas versões mais recentes do Java. Entretanto, ao fazê-lo assim mesmo, você denuncia logo de cara a presença de eventuais erros de classpath. Além disso, ele só precisa ser feito uma vez, durante o carregamento do programa, e se falhar, o programa está irremediavelmente quebrado. Assim sendo, esse processo pode ser mantido em um bloco de inicialização estático.

Esse mecanismo era responsável por garantir que a classe do driver fosse carregada. Uma vez carregada, a classe efetua o seu próprio registro como um driver SQL, passando a ser reconhecido pela classe `DriverManager` como tal. **A partir do Java 6, você não precisa mais usá-lo.**

## Um pouco de reflection

Para todas as classes carregadas na JVM, existe um objeto da classe `java.lang.Class` correspondente. Para obter-se uma classe a partir de seu nome, você pode usar o método [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-).

O [`newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), é o método responsável por chamar o construtor sem parâmetros de uma dada classe a partir do objeto `Class` correspondente. Uma vez que ele invoca o construtor, ele naturalmente retorna a instância criada. Com isso, é possível criar-se instâncias de classes a partir do objeto `Class`.

Note que a partir do Java 9, esse método foi tornado obsoleto porque ele não se comporta bem no caso do construtor lançar uma exceção. A alternativa é trocar `newInstance()` por `getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`.

## A classe `ServiceLoader`

Com o advento do [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) no Java 6, o uso explícito do `Class.forName(String)` para esse caso tornou-se desnecessário, pois o `ServiceLoader` é o mecanismo que permite enumerar-se automaticamente serviços dentro de JARs que implemente uma determinada interface e é esse mecanismo que os drivers usam para enumerar-se a si mesmos sem que o programador precise se preocupar com isso.

Por exemplo, se você abrir o seu [`mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar) como se fosse um arquivo ZIP, você encontrará um arquivo chamado `java.sql.Driver` dentro de uma pasta chamada `META-INF/services`. Eis o conteúdo desse arquivo:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```

Quando o `ServiceLoader` for procurar por implementações da interface `java.sql.Driver`, ele vai [procurar pelo arquivo `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` dentro de cada JAR](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ServiceLoader.java#344), e em cada JAR onde esse arquivo for encontrado, será dele lida uma lista com o nome das implementações. Em seguida, o `ServiceLoader` vai [carregar cada uma dessas classes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ServiceLoader.java#370) e então, a medida que for carregando elas,
 [chamar o método `newInstance()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ServiceLoader.java#380), mantendo as instâncias produzidas em um `Map`.

No entanto, como [o `ServiceLoader` é utilizado internamente pela classe `DriverManager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/sql/DriverManager.java#586), você não precisa interagir diretamente com ele (nem precisa saber que existe) e nem precisa mais efetuar o `Class.forName(String)` manualmente. A única coisa que você precisa fazer é usar o `DriverManager` diretamente:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
```

## O que a classe do `Driver` faz afinal?

Vamos dar uma olhada no [código-fonte da classe `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java):

```
package com.mysql.jdbc;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * The Java SQL framework allows for multiple database drivers. Each driver should supply a class that implements the Driver interface
 * 
 * <p>
 * The DriverManager will try to load as many drivers as it can find and then for any given connection request, it will ask each driver in turn to try to
 * connect to the target URL.
 * 
 * <p>
 * It is strongly recommended that each Driver class should be small and standalone so that the Driver class can be loaded and queried without bringing in vast
 * quantities of supporting code.
 * 
 * <p>
 * When a Driver class is loaded, it should create an instance of itself and register it with the DriverManager. This means that a user can load and register a
 * driver by doing Class.forName("foo.bah.Driver")
 */
public class Driver extends NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
    //
    // Register ourselves with the DriverManager
    //
    static {
        try {
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
        } catch (SQLException E) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new driver and register it with DriverManager
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if a database error occurs.
     */
    public Driver() throws SQLException {
        // Required for Class.forName().newInstance()
    }
}
```

Observe que há um bloco de inicialização estática que instancia a classe e a registra no `DriverManager`. Dessa forma, quando a classe é carregada, a instância necessária do driver já é criada. Ou seja, quando um `Class.forName(String)` for executado (seja por você ou seja indiretamente pelo `ServiceLoader`), ela já vai ser instanciada.

## Posso chamar o `newInstance()` mesmo assim?

Se você quiser usar o `Class.forName(String)` mesmo assim, ao chamar o `newInstance()`, você vai criar uma outra instância que não estará registrada no `DriverManager` e ao não atribuir ela a lugar nenhum, será logo descartada pelo coletor de lixo. Ou seja, a chamada explícita a `newInstance()` é totalmente inútil e desnecessária.

Entretanto, ter várias instâncias do driver não é nocivo. De fato, uma é registrada no `DriverManager` pelo inicializador estático e uma segunda instância é criada pelo `ServiceLoader`. Se você usar o `newInstance()`, vai criar uma terceira instância também (ainda mais se você atribuí-la a alguma variável e utilizá-la posteriormente).

Seria de se esperar que o fato de existir mais do que uma instância do driver pudesse acarretar problemas, mas não acarreta devido a forma como ele é implementado. Se você olhar no [código-fonte da superclasse de `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, que é a classe `com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java), você verá que todos os campos são estáticos e compartilhados por quaisquer instâncias que venham a existir. Logo, se todas as instâncias compartilham o mesmo estado e não mantêm nenhum estado em si próprias, todas têm o mesmo comportamento e operam sobre os mesmos dados.

## E se eu importar o driver diretamente?

Ao importar o driver diretamente, se você puder garantir que o seu código irá carregá-la, o inicializador estático dela vai ser executado e ela vai se registrar no `DriverManager`.

Usar uma `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class` no meio do código não é o suficiente para garantir o carregamento da classe. Mas, se você usar uma dessas coisas, aí funciona:

```
Class<?> x = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class;
```

Ou então:

```
new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
```

Ou seja, desde que você lembre-se de que pode haver várias instâncias equivalentes do driver por aí, você pode fazer isso sim e não haverá nenhum problema.