# Problemas para conectar Postgres com java

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, conexão

Bom, estou com um problema para fazer a conexão da minha aplicação java com meu banco de dados (Estou usando o pgAdmin4 que basicamente é postgres).

Codigo java:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

private static final String DRIVER = "org.postgressql.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/NomedoDB";
private static final String USER = "postgres";
private static final String PASS = "";

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);

        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão", ex);
    }
}
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ConnectionFactory conn = new ConnectionFactory();
    conn.getConnection();
}
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Erro na conexão
>       at ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:22)
>       at BDLearning.main(BDLearning.java:22)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgressql.Driver
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>       at ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:18)
>       ... 1 more

Eu vi em alguns lugares que poderia ser o driver do postgres, mas eu já tentei com vários e mesmo assim não funcionou, atualmente estou usando [estas aqui](http://prntscr.com/gu7xpo) que foram baixadas em https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current

Comment: Através de qual IDE vocês está desenvolvendo? Seu projeto segue o modelo Maven?

Comment: Acredito que só precisa adicionar um jar ao seu projeto, no caso deveriam ser retirados os jre6 e 7 que você colocou. Veja isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242714/por-que-utilizar-class-forname-ao-conectar-com-o-banco-de-dados/242765#242765 pode ajudar também.

Comment: @Krismorte, estou usando Netbeans, e não, não segue Maven.

Comment: @GustavoFragoso retirei a jre6 e 7 e continuou dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Você precisa adiaionar ao seu classpath o jar do postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demorei um pouco para perceber seu erro, é simples questão de digitação pois o nome correto do driver é `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` você colocou 2 's'.

Comment: Eu já tinha reparado isso antes, mas acho que dei um ctrl+z quando estava fazendo os testes da galera de cima. Acho que o fato de eu ter tirado as 2 'jars' que estavam sobrando e sua ajuda deram certo. Valeu !