# Erro de SQLException ao tentar conectar no banco de dados

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou criando um projeto com JDBC. Quando executo o código ele dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Carro
>   at ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:32)

Já chequei se o nome do meu banco está correto e o driver do conector já está dentro do meu projeto.

Código:

```
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    public  Connection getConnection() {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Carro";
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Você adicionou o driver do mysql no classpath? O erro acusa que o driver não foi encontrado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, verifique se o driver do MySQL está em seu classpath. Você pode baixar O JAR da versão 8.0.8-dmr do driver [**aqui**](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.8-dmr/mysql-connector-java-8.0.8-dmr.jar). Ao colocar-se o driver no classpath, esse problema deve se resolver.

Mas, há mais um sério problema que você deve resolver. **Você está manipulando o banco de dados na mesma thread do swing.** Isso pode deixar a aplicação não-responsiva. [O motivo é que o banco de dados pode demorar um pouco para fazer a requisição, e durante esse período, a sua tela ficará congelada.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132) Para resolver isso, procure utilizar a classe [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) de forma a não deixar o swing travar por estar fazendo operações no banco de dados.

Veja também [**essa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242765/132) para maiores informações.