# Refatorar o código usando o factory pattern sem o uso da condição if-elseif

Tags: java, design-pattern

Tenho o seguinte `Factory`. Nele eu instancio uma classe responsavel por dar parse no arquivo em questão. Para que seja instanciado esse parser, primeiramente é verificado nas condições se aquele parser é o correto para realizar o processamento.

```
public class InvoiceParserFactory
{
    public static InvoiceParser getParser(InvoicePdfReader reader)
    {
        String invoiceText = reader.getText();

        if (isXxxParser(invoiceText)) {
            return new XXX_PARSER(invoiceText);
        }
        else if (isYyyParser(invoiceText)) {
            return new YYY_PARSER(invoiceText);
        }
        else {
            throw new InvoiceException("Can't find parser.");
        }
    }

    private static boolean is_XXX_PARSER(String invoiceText) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xxx_regex");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(invoiceText);

        //as condições aqui são diferentes, portanto não da pra simplificar esses métodos
    }

    private static boolean is_YYY_PARSER(String invoiceText) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("yyy_regex");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(invoiceText);

        //as condições aqui são diferentes, portanto não da pra simplificar esses métodos
    }
}
```

Aqui um exemplo de um `PARSER`:

```
public final class XXX_PARSER extends InvoiceParser
{
    @Override
    protected void parseSomeText() {
        //implementação
    }
}
```

Essa lógica não escala nesse design pattern, já que terei centenas ou até milhares de `PARSERS`. Vi em alguns exemplos que seria interessante colocar todos os `PARSERS` em uma collection e implementar um método estatico em cada `PARSER` para verificar se o `PARSER` em questão é o que precisa ser instanciado. Só que ai me depararia com a necessidade de instanciar o `PARSER` antes mesmo de usa-lo, pois teria que usar talvez `Set<InvoiceParser>` e depois `set.add(new XXX_PARSER)` e assim em diante, só que se eu instanciar dessa maneira em uma collection eu quebro todo meu algoritmo que está baseado no construtor da classe InvoiceParser, que é pai de todos os PARSERS.

Qual seria a melhor forma de refatorar esse Factory para que atenda minha necessidade?

Comment: Se guardar um set do tipo `Class<?>` não precisa de instanciar de antemão os vários parsers. Pode ate guardar um map com a class e respetiva regex, e se algum dos elementos jogar, instancia o parser por reflexão.

Comment: Qual versão do Java você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou utilizando Java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar uma `enum` com um elemento para cada tipo de *parser*. Nela você teria a forma como o *parser* é criado e o *pattern* correspondente. Exemplo:

Classe `InvoiceParser`:

```
private abstract class InvoiceParser {/*métodos da classe*/}
```

Duas implementações como exemplo:

```
private class XxxParser extends InvoiceParser {
    public XxxParser(String text) {}
}
```

E:

```
private class YyyParser extends InvoiceParser {
    public YyyParser(String text) {}
}
```

A `enum` com um *factory method* que encontra o *parser* adequado:

```
public enum Parser {
    //O primeiro parâmetro é a regex
    //o segundo é a forma como se cria o parser
    XXX_PARSER("xxx_regex", XxxParser::new),

    YYY_PARSER("yyy_regex", YyyParser::new);

    //interface com um método para criar o parser
    //permite o uso de lambda e method references
    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface ParseCreator {
        InvoiceParser create(String text);
    }

    //cache interno
    private static final Parser[] VALUES = Parser.values(); 

    private final Pattern pattern;

    private final ParseCreator creator;

    private Parser(String regex, ParseCreator creator) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    //factory method que encontra o parser adequado ao reader
    public static final InvoiceParser forReader(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        for(Parser parser : VALUES) {
            if(parser.pattern.matcher(reader.getText()).find()) {
                return parser.creator.create(reader.getText());
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Caso a *regex* não seja o único critério utilizado para identificar o parser adequado, você poderia adicionar a `enum` um objeto responsável por verificar esses critérios adicionais específicos de cada *parser*, nesse caso a `enum` ficaria dessa forma:

```
public enum Parser {
    //o primeiro parâmetro é a regex
    //o segundo é a forma como se cria o parser
    //o terceiro são os critérios adicionais
    XXX_PARSER("xxx_regex", XxxParser::new, reader -> {
        //suas condições adicionais
        return true;
    }),

    YYY_PARSER("yyy_regex", YyyParser::new, reader-> {
        //suas condições adicionais
        return true;
    });

    //interface com um método para criar o parser
    //permite o uso de lambda e method references
    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface ParseCreator {
        InvoiceParser create(String text);
    }

    //interface com um método para verificar se o parser é o adequado
    //permite o uso de lambda e method references
    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface Parseable {
        boolean canParse(InvoicePdfReader reader);
    }

    //cache interno
    private static final Parser[] VALUES = Parser.values();

    private final Pattern pattern;

    private final ParseCreator creator;

    private final Parseable parseable;

    private Parser(String regex, ParseCreator creator, Parseable parseable) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        this.creator = creator;
        this.parseable = parseable;
    }

    //factory method que encontra o parser adequado ao reader
    public static final InvoiceParser forReader(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        for(Parser parser : VALUES) {
            if(!parser.pattern.matcher(reader.getText()).find()) {
                continue;
            }
            //verifica os critérios específicos do parser
            if(parser.parseable.canParse(reader)) {
                return parser.creator.create(reader.getText());
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Para encontrar o *parser adequado* bastaria fazer:

```
InvoiceParser parser = Parser.forReader(reader);
```

Comment: Quando se usa o XxxParser::new é instanciado de imediato o parser? Ou seja, todos os parsers colocados no enum são pré-instanciados? Se sim, isso seria um problema pois eu teria que tirar lógicas do construtor dos parsers

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Não. Cada vez que você evoca o método `create` na linha `return parser.creator.create(reader.getText());` ele vai criar um novo *parser*.

Comment: Não seria uma "melhor prática" usar um Map estático com todos os parsers ao invés de Enum?

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Não acho que exista uma "melhor prática" para esse caso. É simplesmente uma questão de utilizar a melhor solução para o problema. Se você acha que utilizar um `Map` vai ser a melhor, seja por um aumento de performance, melhora na legibilidade ou mesmo manter certa consistência no código (caso, por exemplo, você tenha solucionado problemas parecidos com um `Map`) vá em frente e use, não há problema algum.

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Só seriam necessárias algumas adaptações (a criação de uma nova classe para agrupar algum dos valores), visto que, na segunda `enum`, são utilizados 3 parâmetros no construtor, enquanto um `Map` só aceita 2 valores (chave e valor).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Esse é o mecanismo que foi introduzido no Java 6 para resolver problemas exatamente desse tipo que você tem. No seu caso, o `InvoiceParserFactory` corresponde a um serviço. As implementações desse serviço estão espalhadas no classpath/modulepath em um monte de lugares. A função do `ServiceLoader` é encontrar todas as implementações, instanciá-las e dar o resultado.

Primeiro, vamos dar uma mexida na sua classe `InvoiceParserFactory` (que se tornou uma interface):

```
package com.example.invoice;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public interface InvoiceParserFactory {
    public boolean acceptsText(String text);

    public default boolean acceptsText(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        return acceptsText(reader.getText());
    }

    public InvoiceParser newParser(String text);

    public default InvoiceParser newParser(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        return newParser(reader.getText());
    }

    public static InvoiceParser getParser(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        ServiceLoader<InvoiceParserFactory> loader =
                ServiceLoader.load(InvoiceParserFactory.class);

        for (InvoiceParserFactory factory : loader) {
            if (factory.acceptsText(reader)) {
                return factory.newParser(reader);
            }
        }

        throw new InvoiceException("Can't find parser.");
    }
}
```

Essa interface aproveita-se do fato de que a partir do Java 8, interfaces podem ter métodos estáticos ou com implementações `default`. A partir do Java 9, métodos privados também são permitidos em interfaces.

Vamos supor que essa interface está dentro do JAR `invoice-api.jar`.

Então, no arquivo `xxx.jar`, você põe essa classe:

```
package com.example.xxx.invoice;

import com.example.invoice.InvoiceParserFactory;

public class XxxInvoiceParserFactory implements InvoiceParserFactory {
    // ...

    public XxxInvoiceParserFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsText(String text) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xxx_regex");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(invoiceText);
        // ...        
    }

    @Override
    public InvoiceParser newParser(String text) {
        return new XxxParser(text);
    }
}
```

Dentro do `xxx.jar`, você põe um arquivo com o mesmo nome da classe/interface do serviço oferecido (não da implementação) dentro de uma pasta chamada `services` dentro da pasta `META-INF`. Por exemplo, no caso acima, o arquivo se chamaria `META-INF/services/com.example.invoice.InvoiceParser`. Dentro desse arquivo você põe o nome completo da classe implementadora:

```
com.example.xxx.invoice.XxxInvoiceParserFactory
```

Vamos supor que o JAR `yyy.jar` tenha duas implementações distintas de `InvoiceParser`, uma chamada `YyyBlueInvoiceParser` e a outra `YyyRedInvoiceParser`. Nesse caso no arquivo `META-INF/services/com.example.invoice.InvoiceParser` **dentro desse outro JAR** você põe isso:

```
com.example.yyy.invoice.YyyBlueInvoiceParserFactory
com.example.yyy.invoice.YyyRedInvoiceParserFactory
```

Ou seja, o que acontece é que cada JAR tem dentro da pasta `META-INF/services`, arquivos com os nomes dos serviços oferecidos, dentro de cada um desses arquivos, está o nome das implementações existentesa par esses serviços.

Uma aplicação que tenha `xxx.jar`, `yyy.jar` e `invoice-api.jar` no classpath conseguirá enxergar essas três implementações. Para alterar as implementações é fácil, basta que cada JAR que contenha alguma(s) implementação(ões) do seu serviço a(s) declare dentro do `META-INF/services/com.example.invoice.InvoiceParser` dentro do próprio JAR e então é só adicionar o JAR ao classpath e o `ServiceLoader` o encontrará.

Entretanto, há um porém. Para que o `ServiceLoader` possa localizar e instanciar os serviços, eles devem estar em classes públicas, ter um construtor público sem parâmetros e a classe correspondente tem que ser uma implementação ou subclasse do serviço oferecido.

Idealmente você deveria ter as subclasses de `InvoiceParser` como serviço ao invés das implementações de `InvoiceParserFactory`. Entretanto, para conseguir isso, você precisa refatorar as suas subclasses de `InvoiceParser` de uma forma que consiga se livrar da necessidade de ter o PDF como parâmetro para poder ter um construtor sem parâmetros.

Há uma outra forma de oferecer serviços em JARs modulares (Java 9+) que estejam no modulepath ao invés do classpath, mas isso é um pouco mais complicado. O [javadoc da classe `ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) descreve isso com detalhes.

Também já falei um pouco sobre o `ServiceLoader` [nessa outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242765/132).

Comment: Não seria o ServiceLoader que preciso, acredito que é muito mais simples do que você acabou imaginando. O regex serve para identificar o formato/tipo da fatura, e após identificar esse formato, instanciar o parser responsavel de extração de dados dessa fatura. Meu problema era só resolver a quantidade enorme de if-elseif para instanciar esses parsers que se encontram no mesmo JAR. Pois para cada parser, tem um regex que identifica que aquele parser é o que deve ser utilizado, entende? De qualquer forma essa resposta me ajudou pra resolver um problema futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) e então fazer isso:

```
public class InvoiceParserFactory {

    private static final Set<Class<? extends InvoiceParser>> SUB_TYPES;

    static {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.example.meupacote");
        SUB_TYPES = reflections.getSubTypesOf(InvoiceParser.class);
    }

    public static InvoiceParser getParser(InvoicePdfReader reader) {
        String invoiceText = reader.getText();

        for (Class<? extends InvoiceParser> k : SUB_TYPES) {
            try {
                return k.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(invoiceText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Engole e pula.
            }
        }
        throw new InvoiceException("Can't find parser.");
    }
}
```

Em cada implementação de `InvoiceParser`, você deve colocar um construtor que lança uma exceção se a `String` passada não for compatível com ele:

```
public class XxxInvoiceParser extends InvoiceParser {

    // implementação...

    public XxxInvoiceParser(String invoiceText) {
        if (!isXxx(invoiceText)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        // implementação...
    }

    @Override
    protected void parseSomeText() {
        // implementação...
    }

    private static boolean isXxx(String invoiceText) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xxx_regex");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(invoiceText);

        // implementação...
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código vai pegar todas as implementações de InvoiceParser dentro do pacote com.example.meupacote automaticamente? Reflection comparado ao exemplo do @Felipe Marinho, perde em performance? Em escala(muitas implementações de InvoiceParser) seria um problema?

Comment: Sim. Nos pacotes e em quaisquer subpacotes. Não sei acerca da performance, mas uma das finalidades de haver o pacote especificado é exatamente essa. No entanto, eliminar esse custo de desempenho é fácil (alterei a resposta para isso), pois o conjunto de classes só precisa ser pesquisado uma vez.

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Ainda existe um gargalo de que ele tem que testar todas as implementações uma por uma até achar aquela que é adequada. Se esses testes forem pesados, encontrar a implementação correta é complicado. Entretanto, tanto o código da sua pergunta como todas as respostas aqui descritas tem esse mesmo problema. A solução é que as implementações rejeitem um PDF que não lhes pertençam o mais rápido possível por meio de testes muito simples e óbvios e com isso, mesmo com milhares de implementações distintas, o impacto seja pequeno.